# lenient and diacritic insensitive matching script improve

Tags: javascript, regex, diacritics

I have this script work very nice able to match text with lenient and diacritic insensitive as follows :

https://jsfiddle.net/nvdhqf23/11/

I need also to improve the script to match text with new line break `<br>` in between like this:

```
hello <br> world 
or
hello <br /> world
```

so I need to modify the script regex to match newline breaks :

```
   var inputPattern = XRegExp('('+input.split(' ').join('[\\n\\r\\s\\p{P}\\p{S}]+')+')',"g");
```

Comment: Ìf you want to match `br`, you can add it as an alternative: replace `'(^|[\\s\\p{P}\\p{S}])('+input.split` with `'(^|[\\s\\p{P}\\p{S}])(<br\s*/\s*>|'+input.split`.

Comment: sorry i want to modify the phrase one :
 XRegExp('('+input.split(' ').join('[\\n\\r\\s\\p{P}\\p{S}]+')+')',"g");